# Rename row in df according ot another and sort as well in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello I have 2 dataframes

**DF1**

```
COL1 COL2 COLX
SEQ6 A 1
SEQ2 B 2
SEQ4 C 3
SEQ1 D 4
SEQ7 D 5
```

**DF2**

```
COL1 COL3
SEQ1 Q
SEQ2 L
SEQ3 O
SEQ4 O
SEQ5 M
SEQ6 L
SEQ7 Y
SEQ8 G
```

and the idea is to change the rownames of the `DF1` according to rownames in `DF2`. And then sort the rownames in the same way as `DF2`

The expected result would be :

```
COL1 COL2 COLX
SEQ1 D 4
SEQ2 B 2
SEQ3 NA NA
SEQ4 C 1
SEQ5 NA NA
SEQ6 A 1
SEQ7 D 5
SEQ8 NA NA
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There is no concept of rownames in `dplyr`...

Comment: Just join the two dataframes `dplyr::left_join(df2, df1, by = 'COL1')` Or `merge(df2, df1, by = 'COL1', all.x = TRUE)` in base R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` from *base* like:

```
DF2$COL2 <- DF1$COL2[match(DF2$COL1, DF1$COL1)]
DF2[-2]
#  COL1 COL2
#1 SEQ1    D
#2 SEQ2    B
#3 SEQ3 <NA>
#4 SEQ4    C
#5 SEQ5 <NA>
#6 SEQ6    A
#7 SEQ7    D
#8 SEQ8 <NA>
```

In case you have more columns:

```
cbind(DF2, DF1[match(DF2$COL1, DF1$COL1),])
#     COL1 COL3 COL2 COL1 COL2
#4    SEQ1    Q    D SEQ1    D
#2    SEQ2    L    B SEQ2    B
#NA   SEQ3    O <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3    SEQ4    O    C SEQ4    C
#NA.1 SEQ5    M <NA> <NA> <NA>
#1    SEQ6    L    A SEQ6    A
#5    SEQ7    Y    D SEQ7    D
#NA.2 SEQ8    G <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Data:

```
DF1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="COL1 COL2
SEQ6 A
SEQ2 B
SEQ4 C
SEQ1 D
SEQ7 D")

DF2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="COL1 COL3
SEQ1 Q
SEQ2 L
SEQ3 O
SEQ4 O
SEQ5 M
SEQ6 L
SEQ7 Y
SEQ8 G")
```

Comment: and what If I have more Columns in DF1? Because I see that you include DF1$COL2 in the code but in the real df I can have 12-15 more columns. i updated with one more column to explain

Comment: Than use `cbind`. I made an update.